# FirebaseAuth - Get tokenId in Java backend

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication

We have a nodeJs utility for generating Firebase JWT token :

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true) ...
```

I was wondering if I could do something similar in Java to get a similar JWT.

What I have tried so far :

Dependency - *firebase-admin*

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUser(uid) --> this returns UserRecord with no method similar to getIdToken
```

Is there something that I can use here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's designed to not generate JWT tokens in backend systems and backend systems are just meant to be validating tokens.